# Has Channel Image 6.0.3 been made available?

Tags: channel, channel-images

Hi there I just downloaded the latest version and uploaded but the version still says 6.0.2 and the bug persists. Images disappear after setting the cover image.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just change the version in the addon.setup.php to 6.0.3 to trigger it to update and it seems the bug has gone.

Just in case anyone else has the same issue.